# DocuSign - initiate envelope to email without API authentication

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any DocuSign service that allows an API call to initiate an envelope to be sent to email without authentication?  I have a basic public web form with user name, email, and a custom field and I want to add those parameters to a URN, make the call, and let DocuSign send the prepared envelope to the users email (from the webform).

I'm currently able to accomplish this in a roundabout way, by using powerform parameters and an iframe in page.  Is there a cleaner way in which I could get some response I can use to represent completion of the request to the user?

Comment: Why would you want no authentication? Why not just use JWT authentication and dedicate a user to every call? https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PowerForms is the answer. See my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BKfyDSMoSE) about the different programming features available now with PowerForms.

Please update your question with more details on exactly what you'd like the user experience or use case to be--that's not currently handled by PowerForms.  (We're looking at potential improvements.) Thank you.